# NiFi - Salesforce JDBC connection approach

Tags: salesforce, apache-nifi, marklogic-dhf

I am trying to connect a Nifi `QueryDatabaseTable` processor to Salesforce in order to retrieve data to load into a Marklogic data hub.  I found a couple of shareware JDBC drivers for Salesforce but have not been able to successfully connect to the SF Connected App endpoint I've been given.  Can anyone advise whether this is a good approach for automated data retrieval from SF?  Should I be able connect to a SF Connected App URL via JDBC driver like the one at [ascendix](https://github.com/ascendix/salesforce-jdbc)?

TIA!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up finding a free Salesforce JDBC driver (not the ascendix driver, which did not work for me) that seems to work fine for simple select queries to pull data from a Salesforce Connected App.  So, the JDBC approach for this solution works using a Nifi QueryDatabaseTable processor which produces an Avro dataset that is easily split into records and converted to JSON for ingest to MarkLogic.

Comment: which one did you end up using? this one? http://reliersoft.com/download/salesforce-jdbc-driver/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the RelierSoft driver works for me, though the 0.4 version (Oct 2019) of the JAR is packaged with an old version of the apache commons.csv library that causes errors for some latest NiFi services, like CSVReader.  So, I repackaged it without the old commons.csv library classes to make that service work for me.